# read request body in webflux

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-cloud-gateway

```
public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {
    Flux<DataBuffer> body = exchange.getRequest().getBody();
    //Return different according to body content...
    if (condition) {
        return chain.filter(exchange);
    } else {
        return Mono.empty();
    }
}
```

How do I get the body of the request to do some custom judgments in spring-webflux with spring 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not entirely clear. I assume your doubt is what you put in the code snippet comments.

There are probably different ways to achieve what you want. One simple way to do it is by using a [flatMap](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) operator. Somewhat as follows:

```
public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {
    Flux<DataBuffer> body = exchange.getRequest().getBody()
       .flatMap(data -> {
           if (condition) {
              return chain.filter(exchange);
           } 
           return Mono.empty();
       });
  //...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, your answer has solved my doubts.

Comment: Hi,I want to ask you a question. When the body has no content, it seems that the `flatMap` method will not be called, so my logic is incomplete. I found a `switchIfEmpty` can only set the `default body` for a long time, but I did not find a `DataBuffer` how to build a default value.

Comment: Have you read the documentation of [DefaultDataBuffer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/buffer/DefaultDataBuffer.html)?

Comment: Thank you so much,solved.`new DefaultDataBufferFactory().allocateBuffer()`

Comment: @KerwinBryant could you please add your complete answer?